# Has "In class member initialization" feature made into C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, in-class-initialization

[In class initialization feature](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/C++0xFAQ.html#member-init), which allows to initialize normal members inside the class itself,

```
struct A {
  int a = 0; // error: ISO C++ forbids in-class initialization of non-const static member ‘a’
};
```

This is giving error in latest compiler gcc-4.6 (with `-std=c++0x`). Has this feature made into the C++11 standard or gcc still doesn't support it ?

Comment: Your example compiles fine with clang (svn trunk).

Comment: Have you tried with gcc 4.7 ? It may have been incorporated in.

Comment: @Matthieu, with lots of effort I somehow installed gcc-4.6 on installed on Ubuntu a week back, assuming it supports all the features. And now I am learning that gcc-4.7 is already released !! :'(

Comment: I just looked at the release notes (http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.7/changes.html) and it does not seem to have make it in 4.7. Honestly, I find the 4.7 rather light in term of changes (for C++ anyway) though I guess reviewing the two-phase lookup of templates implied some effort!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes, that is legal in C++0x.  There is an example of this at N3290 §12.6.2/8:

```
struct C {
    /* ... */
    int j = 5; // OK: j has the value 5
};
```