# Why specifying the default value outside of a class is allowed but not inside it?

Tags: c++, constructor, c++11, initialization, default-value

```
#include <atomic>
std::atomic<int> outside(1);
class A{
  std::atomic<int> inside(1);  // <--- why not allowed ?
};
```

[error](http://ideone.com/hsYyW):

```
prog.cpp:4:25: error: expected identifier before numeric constant
prog.cpp:4:25: error: expected ',' or '...' before numeric constant
```

In VS11

```
C2059: syntax error : 'constant'
```

Comment: Try inside = std::atomic<int>(0);

Comment: I think there is a historic problem with `()` inside the class. Have you tried `=` instead of braces ?

Comment: @iammilind guess what. It works outside but not inside.....

Comment: [related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6482566/has-in-class-member-initialization-feature-made-into-c11) and [other one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9723164/c11-initializer-lists-uniform-initialization).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In-class initializers do not support the `(e)` syntax of initialization because the committee members that designed it worried about potential ambiguities (For example, the well-known `T t(X());` declaration would be ambiguous and does not specify an initialization but declares a function with an unnamed parameter).

You can say

```
class A{
    std::atomic<int> inside{1};
};
```

Alternatively a default value can be passed in the constructor

```
class A {
  A():inside(1) {}
  std::atomic<int> inside;
};
```

Comment: although correct ATM both gcc and VC11 doesn't support `{1}` :(. +1

Comment: Non-static data member initializers ([N2756](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2008/n2756.htm)) are supported by Clang 3.0 and upwards.

Comment: @MatthieuM. I'm on windows :(. My favorite IDE is VS and i like clang but it doesnt support windows

Comment: @acidzombie24: I can understand the appeal of VS (especially its debugger). As for Windows support in clang, it's moving along but yes, unfortunately, it's still lagging behind. Personally (having a Windows computer at home too), I use codeblocks for edition on a shared folder... and I have a Ubuntu VM for compiling/running my programs :)

Comment: @MatthieuM I'm assuming CB is running in the VM and all the dev work is done there? I test via a poorly written but working `makeIt.sh` in linux and ran once in a while. Everything else is done on windows. I also have a `gccbuild.bat`

Comment: @acidzombie24 [GCC does support it](http://liveworkspace.org/code/0adafb37b55d228ca5a37d3f2efe6123).

Comment: @acidzombie24: Actually no, I am editing on Windows and using VirtualBox ability to share folder between host OS and guest OS to access the files from within the Ubuntu VM to compile them :)

Comment: @LucDanton: darnnnnnn must upgrade :D. Now if only the brand new released less then a month ago VS supported it, i'd be all set :(

Comment: @MatthieuM. nice, how do you send the build command from cb windoze and get the errors/outputs?

Comment: This is C++11 syntax, and it hasn't made it into many compilers yet.