# C++ Error: Expected a type specifier

Tags: c++

When I try to use a `LoggerStream` like this, I get 'expected a type specifier':

`const LoggerStream logger(L"Test Component");`

Here's where I'm trying to use the `LoggerStream`:

```
#include "Logger.h"
#include "TestComponent.h"

namespace ophRuntime {
    struct TestComponent::TestComponentImpl {


        private:
        LoggerStream logger(L"Test Component");

        NO_COPY_OR_ASSIGN(TestComponentImpl);
    };

    TestComponent::TestComponent() : impl(new TestComponentImpl()) {

    }

    bool TestComponent::Init() {

    }
}
```

Comment: Showing the code which generates the error would be helpful. Have you forgotten to `#include "Logger.h"`, for example... And I can't see how Logger_WIN is relevant:  you're not getting an error compiling that - are you?

Comment: @Roddy I added the code. No errors elsewhere.

Comment: Now we're getting somewhere ;-) Check my answer.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can't construct class members like this:-

```
  struct TestComponent::TestComponentImpl 
  {

  private:
        LoggerStream logger(L"Test Component");
```

Instead, use an initialization list in the constuctor, like this:

```
struct TestComponent::TestComponentImpl 
{
   LoggerStream logger;

    TestComponent::TestComponent() : impl(new TestComponentImpl()),
                                     logger("L"Test Component")
    {   
    }

    ...    
}
```

And I think you've fallen foul of the ["Most Vexing Parse"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse) because the compiler thinks `logger` must be a function, and it's complaining that `L"Test Component"` is not a type specifier for a parameter.

Comment: Ah damnit - I'd made a point of educating myself on that one (the most vexing parse) so I didn't get trapped by it... Haha, best laid plans and all that. Thanks for your perseverance :)

Comment: FWIW I'm on C++ 11, so class initialization like that is possible ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6482566/has-in-class-member-initialization-feature-made-into-c11 ). I simply replaced the ()'s with {}'s and all is well.

Answer (score 3):

Do you mention the namespace anywhere? You need to write either:

```
using ophRuntime::LoggerStream;
const LoggerStream logger(L"Test Component");
```

or

```
using namespace ophRuntime;
const LoggerStream logger(L"Test Component");
```

or

```
const ophRuntime::LoggerStream logger(L"Test Component");
```

Comment: The declaration of logger is already in the ophRuntime namespace. Nonetheless I tried adding an explicit specification like that, to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

`LoggerStream` is in namespace `ophRuntime` thus your definition has to be

```
const ophRuntime::LoggerStream logger(L"Test Component");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the namespace name `ophRuntime` when use the class `LoggerStream`:

```
const ophRuntime::LoggerStream logger(L"Test Component");
```